# Alsa Mixer Query?

Tags: sound

Opened the terminal ran alsamixer, held the right arrow key till I could encounter beep mixer, but was unable to find beep GUI.

Does this mean beep is not installed or it has not been invoked or any other scenario?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 3):

When you open `alsamixer` you may first press <kbd>F6</kbd> and select your card. Now you should able to mute the beep with <kbd>M</kbd>. Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> closes `alsamixer`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `alsamixer` simply does not support changing beep's volume.